# Lambda: index.handler is undefined or not exported

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, apollo-server

I have deployed a lambda function using aws amplify, index.ts is as follows:

```
import { graphqlHandler } from '@/graphql';

console.log(graphqlHandler);

exports.handler = graphqlHandler;
```

Here's the webpack config:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const EventHooksPlugin = require('event-hooks-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './build/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@/graphql": path.resolve(__dirname, './build/graphql'),
            "@/generated": path.resolve(__dirname, './build/generated'),
        },
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new EventHooksPlugin({
            'beforeRun': new EventHooksPlugin.CallbackTask((compilation, callback) => {
                return Promise.all([
                    new Promise((resolve) => fs.copy('../../../../graphql', './build/graphql', resolve)),
                    new Promise((resolve) => fs.copy('../../../../generated', './build/generated', resolve)),
                    new Promise((resolve) => fs.copy('./lib/index.ts', './build/index.ts', resolve)),
                    new Promise((resolve) => fs.copy('./lib/package.json', './build/package.json', resolve)),
                ]).then(() => callback());
            }),
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "./build/package.json", to: "./package.json" },
                { from: "../../../../schema.graphql", to: "./schema.graphql" },
                { from: "../../../../prisma/schema.prisma", to: "./schema.prisma"},
                {
                    from: "../../../../node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node",
                    to: "./libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node"
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
};
```

And the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./build/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

When I execute the function, the following is logged:

```
2023-07-20T12:59:34.409Z    undefined   INFO    [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
2023-07-20T12:59:34.421Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
        "    at UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:15)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1192:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1198:1"
    ]
}
```

The index.js file and its dependencies are being loaded, the handler is present, and the handler is exported. How can I get the lambda to execute this function?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack was messing around with the exports. I updated the webpack config as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        library: {
            type: 'commonjs2',
        },
    },
};
```